# Does a strong digraph always admit a vertex that lies on some path between $\Theta(n^2)$ pairs of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be a directed graph.

Call a vertex $v$ in $G$ *central* if there exists $\Theta(n^2)$ distinct pairs of vertices $(u,w)$ such that $v$ lies on some path from $u$ to $w$. We do not care whether these paths are shortest or not, nor whether other paths avoiding $v$ exist.

Question: Do strongly connected digraphs always admit a central vertex?

Comment: I'm confused about a few things here. First, what do you mean by Theta(n) for a specific graph? Is the idea that you want a constant C so that there is a vertex part of at least Cn^2 such paths for all strongly connected digraphs? (Also, I assume n is the number of vertices?)

Also, I would say that every vertex is central for a silly reason: by strong connectedness, for all u,v,w, there is a path from u to v and a path from v to w, so v is on a path from u to w. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the number of vertices. By $\Theta(n^2)$, I am asking if there exists a constant $c$ such that in every strongly connected digraph, at least one vertex lies on a path between $c\cdot n^2$ pairs of vertices. Note that I want a path here, not a walk, i.e. one that cannot visit intermediate vertices twice (otherwise, I would agree with your objection). Perhaps I should have said "self-avoiding path" to avoid this ambiguity. Thanks for asking for these clarifications!

Comment: Ahhhh, OK. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if this wasn't true for *all* strong digraphs, the question could remain open for all sufficiently large strong digraphs (whence the asymptotic notation). So far, I am unaware of such result, so an answer to either version would be great (and worth the bounty ;-)).

Comment: Do you have a proof of the analogous statement for undirected graphs? I guess that by passing to a spanning tree, it suffices to prove the result for trees?

Comment: @Timothy Chow I think what you're referring to is answered by part (iii) of my extended comment below.  That is, every tree T on n vertices has a vertex v such that every component of T-v has order at most n/2.  In this case, v will be a central vertex.

Comment: @LouisD Ah, good. So maybe one can try to make a similar argument about minimal strong digraphs? The paper [Structural and spectral properties of minimal strong digraphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.endm.2016.09.017) looks relevant though I don't immediately see how to use it.

Comment: @LouisD Actually that is a centroidal vertex, not a central vertex. A central vertex minimizes the distance to the furthest leaf.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I had never heard the term centroidal vertex, so that is good to know.  But by "central vertex" I meant it in the way in which it is defined in this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't get the answer you were looking for, but I'd just like to point out that the most promising direction to me is the one pointed out by @TimothyChow (my "answer" was weakened by the thing I pointed out in the addendum).  That is, to focus on minimal strongly connected digraphs.  These are much more complicated than trees, but there are some nice structural results here https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2017.11.027 which could be helpful.  For instance what additional structural properties can be proved under the assumption that there are no paths of length $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: Sure, I did not react to Timothy's comment because we knew about this paper but (so far, from a superficial look) had not found how it could help. We also explored a bit the "what we get if there are no path of linear size" question. In fact, if all the paths are $\Theta(1)$-short, then we also get centrality for free (due to the existence of nodes of linear degrees). Unfortunately, there are graphs whose typical distance is intermediate and no exploitable structure showed up, at least so far. Ideally, we were hoping for that this question would already be settled somewhere, shouldn't it?

Comment: At some point @mhum posted an answer. The answer was incomplete, but it seems that its problems were fixable. Unfortunately, the answer disappeared. Mhum, could you please either repost your answer or contact me? Or tell us why the answer was removed. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnaudCasteigts Oh sorry about that. The approach I had was actually fatally flawed in a number of ways, to the point it was not repairable. Fundamentally, I believed that one of the maximal vertices in one of the Hasse diagrams in the decomposition would have to be one of these central vertices but it is actually not the case. I have a counter-example that I can post as an answer if you're curious.

Comment: @mhum, sure, could you please post the counter-example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this manuscript](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.03567), Bessy, Thomassé, and Viennot proved the following stronger property:

Let $D$ be a strongly connected directed graph, then there is a vertex $v$ in $D$ such that there exists an in-tree towards $v$ and an out-tree from $v$ that are vertex-disjoint (apart from sharing $v$ itself) and contain at least  $n/6$ vertices each.

As a result, $v$ lies on a path between at least $n^2/36$ pairs of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer, but I do have an idea for how a proof could go.  I would make this a comment, but it is too long.

(i) Prove that every 2-strongly connected digraph (i.e. remains strongly connected after the deletion of any vertex, or equivalently, by Menger's theorem, for every pair of vertices x,y, there are two internally disjoint x,y-paths and two internally disjoint y,x-paths) has the property that for every ordered triple of vertices u,v,w there is a uw-path that contains v.
(For graphs, this is a standard application of Menger's theorem, but the same proof doesn't seem to hold for digraphs.)

**BEGIN ADDENDUM:** The reason I couldn't see how to prove (i) is because it is not true.  See the figure on page 2 of "About Some Cyclic Properties in Digraphs" by Heydemann and Sotteau.  They refer to the property that for every ordered triple of vertices u,v,w there is a uw-path that contains v as "property (T)".  They point out that Thomassen proved (Theorem 2 in "Highly connected non-2-linked digraphs") that for every k, there is a k-strongly connected digraph having the property that there are 2-vertices which are non contained together in a cycle and thus property (T) fails.

Of course, this doesn't rule out proving that in a 2-strongly connected digraph on n vertices there is a central vertex, but perhaps even this will be challenging to prove.

I suppose the only takeaway from all of this is that you can at least focus on proving your conjecture for 2-strongly connected digraphs.

**END ADDENDUM**

(ii) For undirected graphs there is the concept of a block-cut tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component).  Basically, this allows you to partition the graph into 2-connected "components" keeping track of the connections between those components.  I don't know the definitive reference for the analogous concept in digraphs, but this paper might be it ("Strong k-connectivity in digraphs and random digraphs" by Reif and Spirakis)

(iii) Every vertex weighted tree T with weights between 0 and 1/2 and summing to 1 over all vertices has the property that there is a vertex v such that every component of T-v has weight at most 1/2 (the unweighted version is a well-known fact https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742440/you-can-always-delete-a-vertex-from-a-tree-g-such-that-the-remaining-connected and the weighted version has basically the same proof).

(iv) Now either there is a 2-strongly connected subdigraph with $\Theta(n)$ vertices and we are done by (i), or every 2-strongly connected subdigraph has order o(n) and then use (ii) and (iii) to get the desired central vertex.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, the T property is stronger than what we want to achieve. It could be worth investigating further in [HS] where the T property breaks in 2-connected digraphs, and see if a "central" vertex still exists in that case. (I will do it eventually if there are no other definite answer.)